# Trace of square matrices , annihilator polynomial and Ricci tensor

Tags: linear-algebra

I think trace of a matrix is extremely important . one reason is, it appears in the annihilator polynomial of that matrix and also we know different applications such as Ricci tensor. why is the sum of the arrays on the main diagonal ( or the sum of eigenvalues) so important ? and it appears in the annihilator polynomial ? why is it the coefficient of that specific term in the annihilator polynomial?